# Everything is ok and x is not disappearing

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, ubuntu, mysql-workbench, errors

Since some time ago, I've started with MySQL so I don't know Workbench very well.

That little red x next to the number of the line that indicates an error does not disappear, even though everything is okay and I fixed what was wrong.

A simple example: `select * project where name='Anna'` and I can execute it but x won't disappear unless I delete everything and type again. This is very annoying and I can't concentrate because of always thinking about what should be wrong.

Could somebody tell me what to do to fix this? :(

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it is a syntax check complaining:

```
select * FROM project where name='Anna'
         ^^^^  -- missing syntax keyword!
```

Comment: But as an example I add some letter or anything and then delete it from the correct line, the x will still be there. That goes for everything I do. Normally, x should appear until the error is corrected, not continue to exist... if you understand what I want to say :)